# Add a sticky header/title row to a select list in mudblazor

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Currently have a select list that has multiple properties associated with the objects. Things like Name, Description and then 3 other properties that probably aren't obvious what they mean to someone that isn't trained (training is not on me though).

What I would like to do is add a sticky header/title row and have it on top whenever the list scrolls. Has anyone tried to do something similar to this?

I've tried adding the data grid and table into the select, but those both render inside and outside of the select list. Also have tried adding divs into the select, which I can get somewhat there with just normal CSS, but they are render outside of the select as well.

Edit:
Reproducible example: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GawnOMPzyqOMbUcz

Comment: Why don't you put together a simple [MRE] to demonstrate what you want.  It's easier to  work with specific code and a context.

Comment: For instance "Currently have a select list that has multiple properties associated with the objects. " is pretty opaque to me.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis sure, sorry about that. Will edit original with link to example